# Need Help Breaking Down a JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

As usual I'll preface this question by stating that I'm very much in the learning phase. I'm attempting to teach myself JavaScript and I'm reading a book. I'll probably go on to read another one when I'm done but right now I need help understanding something. On to the question...

I'll start by including the [Callback] function that's stumping me:

```
function doMath(number1, number2, callback) {
    var result = callback(number1, number2);
    document.getElementById("theResult").innerHTML += ("The result is: " + result + "<br>");
}

document.addEventListener(’DOMContentLoaded’, function() {
    doMath(5, 2, function(number1, number2) {
        var calculation = number1 * number2;
        return calculation;
    });
}, false);
```

For my question, and I'll try to make as much sense as possible here, I just don't understand how the arguments are being passed to the functions.

For example, when we call `doMath` it looks like it includes the argument 5, 2, and then a function. That function appears to have two parameters `number1` and `number2`. I can see that the values of those two parameters are going to be used in the calculation but I'm not seeing how they get there. I thought `5` and `2` would be passed to the `doMath` function above, not used in that parameter function.

These numbers then make it back to the `doMath` function and, again, the numbers are used in the parameters there.

Obviously it does though, right? The problem I have is that the book I'm reading doesn't explain this well at all. Like many other things, it glosses over some of the finer details I feel are necessary to truly understand. On top of that, I have found a few instances of error when he's including HTML to provide full examples. I can only spot this because I know HTML. From a completely newbie standpoint, if I don't fully understand how a function works, how can I properly write one? How can I expect the data to flow properly if I don't understand where it goes and why.

If the answer is 'Yes' that those parameters are passed to the callback function, that's good enough. If anyone would care to break down that flow any further I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick numbered breakdown of the logic flow:

```
function doMath(number1, number2, callback) {
    // 4. doMath() is called from point 3.
    // number1 = 5
    // number2 = 2
    // callback = the function containing 'var calculation = ...'

    // 5. the callback function is executed.
    var result = callback(number1, number2);

    // 7. The result of the callback function (10) is set to the innerHTML 
    // of the below element.
    document.getElementById("theResult").innerHTML += ("The result is: " + result + "<br>");
}

// 1. The DOMContentLoaded event handler is defined
document.addEventListener(’DOMContentLoaded’, function() {
    // 2. The DOMContentLoaded event has fired, so this function handler is executed.

    // 3. doMath is called, with the number 5 & 2, and the below function handler.
    doMath(5, 2, function(number1, number2) {
        // 6. The function is executed in doMath() from point 5
        // number1 = 5 (as per the variable in doMath())
        // number2 = 2 (as per the variable in doMath())
        // note that the variables in this function are entirely separate from those in doMath(). 
        // Despite having the same name, they are in entirely different scopes.

        var calculation = number1 * number2;
        return calculation; // the value of 10 is returned to the call in doMath()
    });
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to see what's happening if you break the callback out into its own function.

```
// doMath has two arguments, 5 and 2
// The result is what is returned from our function
// which used to be `callback` and is now `calculate`
function doMath(number1, number2) {
    var result = calculate(number1, number2);
    ...
}

// This was `callback`. All it does is return the result
// of multiplying 5 and 2
function calculate(number1, number2) {
    var calculation = number1 * number2;
    return calculation;
}

// call doMath with 5 and 2
doMath(5, 2);
```

That's all that's happening. In your example `calculate` is just being passed in as an argument to `doMath` instead.